# Why is this simulated transistor turning on at such a low voltage?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, simulation, fet, multisim

[image: My attempt at a transistor switch circuit.]

I'm trying to simulate (using the Mouser edition of MultiSim) a very basic transistor circuit, above, with a MOSFET acting as a switch. It sort of works, inasmuch as V2 reads 20V when `V1 = 0`, meaning the transistor is not conducting; and reads  20mV when `V1 = 5V`, so it's conducting very well.

My problem is that it seems to start conducting at a very low voltage. Even at `V1 = 0.05V`, `V2 = 20.3 mV`. If I'm reading [this datasheet that Mouser provides](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/196/irf530nspbf-935888.pdf) correctly, it shouldn't start conducting until V1 hits the threshold voltage, somewhere in the 2-4V range. Is that interpretation right? And if it is, what's going on in this circuit?

Comment: 100 kohms is a fairly large value. Just a tiny leakage current through the FET is enough to pull the drain node low. The IRF530N's leakage spec is 25 uA (with 100 V Vds), so it's actually surprising you see 20 V on the drain in the "off" state.

Comment: _"... it shouldn't start conducting until V1 hits the threshold voltage, somewhere in the 2-4V range. Is that interpretation right?"_ - Depends on your definition of "start conducting". IR's definition of "start conducting" is in the rightmost column of the table on page 2 of your datasheet: _Vds = Vgs, Id = 250µA_. So, at a much lower Vds than yours, and passing a current that could be significant for R2. Better read that small print ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what is going on here.  Turn-on is a gradual process, but I agree that your simulation seems to not match the datasheet.

However, you are simulating this MOSFET pretty far outside its "normal operation" window.  This is a fairly high current MOSFET (17 amp continuous), and you are using it in a circuit that only draws a maximum of about 200 uA.  For instance, the leakage current at 25 C is 25 uA.  At 150 C, the max leakage is 250 uA!  I could believe that the transistor model in multisim is not great when you are trying to operate near the leakage current level.

Try decreasing R2 or changing to a more suitably sized MOSFET and see if it works better.

Comment: That did it! I guess it's kind of silly to be paranoid about big currents when they're being simulated, huh?